# How do i working with Arrays in a While loop?

Tags: c#, arrays, while-loop

I have tried to wipe this data while trying to export a database into my program.
The basic problem is that I do not know why he can not use LIKE in my SQL statement.

So I wanted to catch all DataRows and write them into an array, which I can edit later.

The program throws an exception:

Error message: *System.IndexOutOfRangeException: "The index was outside the array area."*

[image: Errorlog with variable values in german]

If I did something unusual or wrong in my Post I sincerely apologies, this is my first entry in this forum.

Code:

```
    public void TestQuery()
    {
        string file = @"C:\Users\Michael\Downloads\7z1900-x64.msi";
        // Get the type of the Windows Installer object
        Type installerType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("WindowsInstaller.Installer");

        // Create the Windows Installer object
        WindowsInstaller.Installer installer = (WindowsInstaller.Installer)Activator.CreateInstance(installerType);

        // Open the MSI database in the input file
        Database database = installer.OpenDatabase(file, 0);

        // Open a view on the Property table for the version property
        View view = database.OpenView("SELECT * FROM `File`");
        
        // Execute the view query
        view.Execute(null);

        // Get the record from the view
        Record record = view.Fetch();

        int i = 1;
        string[] sreturns = new string[60];

        while (record != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ausgabe: " + record.get_StringData(0) + '=' + record.get_StringData(1) + '=' + record.get_StringData(2) + '=' + record.get_StringData(3));
            
            record = view.Fetch();
            
            sreturns[i] = record.get_StringData(0).ToString();
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe the size of sreturns is simply too low ? It is a constant 60, while you can iterate in your while indefinitely. While is a poor design here and should be replaced with a for. That means you should be able to count your collection before iterate on it. Furthermore, sreturns should be a List instead of a fixed length array.

Comment: you can use "break" when max size of your array is reached. i'm not sure array is a good way to use with a database because of the limit, except if you use a limit in your request, but in all case it's better to make a security if you use an array. I hope that helps you.

Answer (score 1):

First thing I see is that you're starting at 1, while (C#) arrays are 0-based.

In you screenshot I see that i is 60, so that would be the problem. Index 60 doesn't actually exist in your array, as it goes from 0 to 59.

Comment: Yeah, sure but this wont change anything beside losing 1 Entry. 
This looks like a infinit loop and i dont know why ?

And i dont know why i cant simply dumb "record" into an array

EDIT: Changed the Array to String[40000]. Still got the same error message.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my reply with the actual mistake. The very last iteration tries to access an index that doesn't exist.

Comment: Coud u elucidate it a bit further ?

Comment: @MichaCan'tBreak  what is actually supposed to be in the msi file and what has been put into the array at that point?
Also, it might just be better to use a List<string> where you can continuously add values to, rather than having a fixed Array.

Comment: I want to get a list, an Array anything wich can give me all Filenames which ends with .exe or .msi in Files. LIKE in the SQL Stament are wont work. Datatable File: imgur.com/lZcd0LF

Comment: How many records is that and what kind of data is in sreturns at that point?

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a list instead of an array?

```
List<string> sreturns  = new List<string>();

    while (record != null)
    {
        try
        {
          Console.WriteLine("Ausgabe: " + record.get_StringData(0) + '=' + record.get_StringData(1) + '=' + record.get_StringData(2) + '=' + record.get_StringData(3));
          record = view.Fetch();
          var result = record.get_StringData(0);
          sreturns.Add(result.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No record...");
        }
    }
```

This way you dont need to worry about the array size - its maintainable -efficient - and if in the future the size change you don't have to worry about it.

List documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: This looks very promising, thank u for that, but i still get a NULL 
 Reference.
Errorlog with Variablevalues. https://imgur.com/T5be6RJ

Comment: Added defensive programming hope it helps

Comment: If i remove the sreturn command and just let it run an write the result into the Console it will work and give me something like:
Ausgabe: 128528008=_7zFM.exe=Fm=7zFM.exe
Ausgabe: 128528008=_7zip32.dll=ShellExt32=7-zip32.dll
Ausgabe: 128528008=_7zip.dll=ShellExt=7-zip.dll
Ausgabe: 128528008=_7zG.exe=Gui=7zG.exe
Ausgabe: 128528008=_7z.dll=Formats=7z.dll

Comment: Sadly the defensive programming coudnt help against a NULLReference.
But for the First time he is actually writing something in sresult :)!
https://imgur.com/cjdTznJ

Comment: The issue was when it was unable to retrieve the record.get_StringData(0). Now this implementation will capture the exception if any and let you know about it.

Comment: Count said 101 Items collected but i cant print it out. Any idea ? For the records it seems to be working fine

Comment: Please see new implementation with try-catch

Comment: Coud someone link a usefull documentation "Working with List's" ? Its probably Layer 8 problem right here ;) or change it in the Answer directly with a filter which will show me everything witch is called *something*.exe or *something*.msi

Comment: What's your latest error message? I do not think the _list_ is the problem.

Comment: got it working just fine. Thank u all for the fast help!

Comment: Fantastic dont forget to upvote and please consider accepting an answer by clicking on that checkmark!

Answer (score 0):

What is the query with LIKE that you have tried? The following should work:

```
SELECT * FROM File WHERE FileName LIKE '%.exe' OR FileName LIKE '%.msi'
```

EDIT: On further investigation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/sql-syntax), the documentation seems to imply that the LIKE operator is not supported. But you could start off with an `IS NOT NULL` and do more complex filtering in the loop, like you're doing.

EDIT 2, expanding on Alex Leo's answer.

```
List<string> sreturns  = new List<string>();

    while (record != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ausgabe: " + record.get_StringData(0) + '=' + record.get_StringData(1) + '=' + record.get_StringData(2) + '=' + record.get_StringData(3));
        var result = record.get_StringData(0);
        if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result) && (result.EndsWith(".exe") || result.EndsWith(".msi")))
        {
          sreturns.Add(result.ToString());
        }
        record = view.Fetch();
    }
```

Note that the `view.Fetch()` inside the while loop has been moved to the end, or you would skip the first record, as well as get another null reference when the last record has already been read, but the while loop executes one more time.

Comment: woud have thought so aswell, but view cant work with LIKE. Get COMExeptions all the time.

A better SQL Query woud result all my problems!

Comment: coud u give an example for looping further ?

Comment: Edited the post again with the code for the loop, this will only put the desired records into the collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `i < sreturns.Length` to make sure you are in the array range.
Also, make sure you start with `i = 0` and not 1.

```
int i = 0;
string[] sreturns = new string[60];
        while (record != null && i < sreturns.Length)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ausgabe: " + record.get_StringData(0) + '=' + record.get_StringData(1) + '=' + record.get_StringData(2) + '=' + record.get_StringData(3));

            record = view.Fetch();

            sreturns[i] = record.get_StringData(0).ToString();
            i++;
        }
```